# Как правильно добавить счётчик?

Tags: c#, интерфейс, clr

Хочу добавить счётчик книг к этому проекту (он не мой) : https://github.com/shwanoff/BookShop/tree/master
Пришёл к тому, что не могу грамотно реализовать идею.
Получилось так:

```
 public interface IBook
{
    string Author { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Price { get; set; }
}


public interface ICounter
{
    int Count { get; set; }

    void Reduce(int count = 1);
    void Add(int count = 1);
}


public class Book : IBook, ICounter
{
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public void Add(int count = 1)
    {
        realisation;
    }

    public void Reduce(int count = 1)
    {
        realisation;
    }
}
```

Хочу понять как это сделать, и почему.

Comment: Что такое "счетчик" в вашем понимании? Они ведь бывают разные, например, посчитать сколько книг в магазине, счетчик? Да. Ну а чтоб это сделать, достаточно добавить одну строку после [получения всех книг](https://github.com/shwanoff/BookShop/blob/master/BookShop.App.Cmd/Program.cs#L117), что-то по типу `var count = books.Count();`, а дальше делать с этим значением что угодно, например вывести на экран: `Console.WriteLine($"В магазине {count} книг");`. Как видите, каждый по своему понимает "счетчик", поэтому всегда старайтесь задавать вопрос максимально развернуто!

Comment: Простите за занудство, но Вы уверены, что кол-во книг должно являться свойством книги? Имя, автор, ISDN и т.д. - да, но кол-во относится к полке, складу и т.д..

Comment: @XelaNimed В том то и дело что нет :D Я хочу сделать это правильно. Хочу дать пользователю возможность купить несколько единиц конкретной книги за раз. По моему мой метод противоречит признаку "инкапсуляция".

Comment: Так вроде как в проекте уже [реализован](https://github.com/shwanoff/BookShop/blob/b5017f5ce130880cf144fceec17189789a94c93e/BookShop.Data.Sql/BookShopContext.cs#L9C12-L9C12) репозиторий... В комментарии выше Евгений привёл Вам пример получения количества книг.